# How to gitignore particular files

Tags: python, django, git

I am trying to add a few files to `.gitignore`, but not having luck:

```
# -- in my .gitignore file --

# other items
settings_staging.py
settings_production.py
```

And to test it I'm doing:

```
$ git check-ignore settings_staging.py
```

I know my `.gitignore` is working and including some files, such as the `__pycache__` files, but how do I get it to ignore particular files I specify?

Incidentally, if I change the name of the file to `staging.py` and use the following, it works in the gitignore:

```
*staging.py    

$ git check-ignore staging.py
staging.py
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not having luck"? If you want to ignore files that are already tracked you have to tell git that these files should be deleted from source control `git rm --cached setting_staging.py`

Comment: @HåkenLid oh, got it -- this is the correct answer. If you want to put this in an answer I'll go ahead and answer it -- thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll mark it as a duplicate instead. You're not the first person that had this problem.

Comment: Note that when you use `git rm --cached` you are setting yourself up for future pain: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52743969/1256452